# TFS 2010 Query - Compare two fields

Tags: tfs

Using TFS 2010.
Creating a new query and in the filters added a comparison between two similar type fields i.e. Estimated Work < Remaining Work.

Estimated Work is my custom int field while Remaining Work is a build in TFS field.
I can run the query which returns results, but when trying to save the query I get the following error:

TF26210: 'Remaining Work' is not a supported reference field name. Only reference field names can be used in stored queries.

So can one compare two fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the operator `< [Field]` instead of `<`
 :
[image]

Comment: Awesome, that did the job. Thanks